# disable two finger scrolling on ipad

Tags: css, ipad, scroll

I recently took on a site where there is an issue with the Ipad, it seems to only scroll vertically with 2 fingers, not one, is there any way to disable this and allow it to work normally, I'm unsure what to include but here is my css...

```css
#page {
    margin :0 auto; 
    width: 1003px; 
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}  

html[style] { 
    height: auto !important; 
    position: relative !important; 
    overflow: visible !important; 
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

body[style] { 
    height:auto !important; 
    min-height: 0px !important; 
    position: relative !important; 
    overflow: visible !important; 
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Comment: Why are you changing `overflow`?

Comment: because I noticed that the body had `overflow-x:hidden` as an inline style, and even though I know that shouldnt have anything to do with it I wanted to rule it out completely.

Comment: I had a jquery.ui.touch.js file on the site preventing a vertical scroll. The issue is now resolved.

Comment: please add this as answer and mark your question as solved, but normally you just need to catch the touch event and prevent the default action stackoverflow.com/questions/2890361/disable-scrolling-in-an-iphone-web-application

Comment: OP answered own question in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had originally thought my answer wouldnt be relevant or too far a stretch from the problem so i had left it in the comments. I was going to delete the question but some people seem to benefit from the answer so here is the comment...

I had a jquery.ui.touch.js file on the site preventing a vertical scroll. The issue is now resolved